# rewrite rules for custom post-type with a custom taxonomy

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a custom post type ('post' capabilities) called EVENTS and a custom taxonomy called VENUES (hierarchical).

I want to be able to set the post's url to domain.com/my-events/%TAXONOMY%/%POST-TYPE% kind of like category/post-name, but it doesn't seem to work, the URL always render the %TAXONOMY% bit as is leaving the % signs..

Any ideas?

ps. @John P Bloch, I'm using your plugin.

Comment: I just updated my answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My plugin will be adding this functionality in the next release (in beta now). If you want, you can download the beta at http://www.johnpbloch.com/custom-post-permalinks.zip

There are still known bugs in that beta version, though. I don't have the time to give you a proper answer on here at the moment (it's a pretty complicated fix); we'll see if I release the new version before I get around to it... ;)

### EDIT

My plugin is now in its release candidate phase. If there are no more bugs found by Thursday morning, I'll release it. I don't anticipate this happening, though. You can find the release candidate at the same url as above. I think that should solve your problem. Taxonomy tags are the taxonomy's name (as registered. This may be different from the label).